# How to wait first dispatch to finish execution

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 dispatch_async() like this :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    /* Code here */
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    /* Code here */
}
```

I want the second dispatch to wait until the first one finish his execution. how i can do that ?

Thank's in advance

Comment: What do you want to do with this structure? Just put both code parts after each other into one dispatch_async.

Comment: I have 2 third-party library method that use try catch and i want the second method to start until the first one finish execution

Comment: Well then code differents answer will do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a few solutions, in the order of increasing complexity:

### 1

---

The simplest way is to include both code blocks in the same async calls:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    // code block 1

    // code block 2
}
```

### 2

---

If you don't know precisely when they will run, for example, `code block 1` is triggered when user presses a button and `code block 2` is run when user presses another button, use a serial queue:

```
let serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mySerialQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
    // code block 1
}   
dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
    // code block 2
}
```

### 3

---

If your code blocks run asynchronously, like first making a webservice call to authenticate, then making a second call to get the user's profile, you have to implement waiting:

```
let groupID = dispatch_group_create()

let task1 = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request1) { data, response, error in
    // handle the response...

    // Tell Grand Central Dispatch that the request is done
    dispatch_group_leave(groupID)
}

let task2 = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request2) { data, response, error in
    // handle the response...
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
    dispatch_group_enter(groupID) // Tell GCD task1 is starting
    task1.resume()

    dispatch_group_wait(groupID, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER) // Wait until task1 is done
    task2.resume()
}
```

### 4

---

For anything more complicated, I strongly suggest you learn [`NSOpereationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/). There's a [WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/) on it

Comment: There's no need to block the global queue with `dispatch_group_wait`, and thus occupying a thread. Using `dispatch_group_notify` is preferable.